# Struct defined but compiler claiming it isn't

Tags: c, struct, ncurses

I've started learning C. I wanted to learn how to use the ncurses library and found a 'tutorial' that was more of an instruction by example type.

http://xn--ncoder-9ua.dk/blog/2010/04/using-ncurses-in-c-for-text-user-interfaces-featuring-xcode/

In the tutorial, there is a struct defines with the code:

```
typedef struct Snakepart {
          int x;
          int y;
} Snakeypart;
```

Then I get this error when I try to compile:

```
snake.c:47:9: error: member reference base type 'Snakeypart [40]' is not a
  structure or union
```

Which refers to this line of code:

```
snakey.x = sbegx + i;
```

The variable snakey is defined earlier within main() using the code:

```
Snakeypart snakey[SNAKEY_LENGTH];
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error when the structure has been defined. I'm fairly new to programming in C, but I understand some concepts that are beyond my ability to code, so don't be afraid to get a little technical if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried typedef struct { /* ... */ } Snakeypart?

Comment: `snakey` is defined as an array, not a `Snakeypart`... you want something like `snakey[0].x`

Answer (score 4):

You need to call an element in your array.

For instance:

```
snakey[0].x = sbegx + i;
```

When you create snakey using `snakey[SNAKEY_LENGTH];`, your program creates an array of SNAKEY_LENGTH structures.
You can access the j-th structure in your array by using `snakey[j]`.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I was looking at it too hard, to make it even more obvious, the entry should have been snakey[i].x because it's inside a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
snakey[n].x = sbegx + i;
```

--This might do : n is int

Cuz .. snakey is an array!!!

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was looking at it too hard it seems.